# Finding the midpoint of two lines and the distance between them with Python OpenCv or Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, geometry

I'm trying to make a lane tracking system with python opencv and numpy.

[image: 1]

I have progressed as far as it appears in the photo and I have 3 lines in my hand like this

Let's just say the code I'm using is like this

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("D:/object_detection/images/siyah.jpg")

cv2.line(img, (778, 519), (957, 693), (255,0,0),6)
cv2.line(img, (218, 632), (445, 477), (255,0,0),6)
cv2.line(img, (137, 485), (17, 516), (255,0,0),6)

cv2.imshow("img",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

now i have two questions

1 - distance between two lines

- measure the distance between right lane and middle lane
- measure the distance between the left lane and the middle lane

2 - midpoint between two lines

- find the right lane and middle lane midpoint
- find left lane and middle lane midpoint

Comment: you have line segments. the corresponding lines _intersect_ since they aren't parallel. what "distance" would you consider? you could consider the midpoint of each line, then the distance of two midpoints to each other? or find the intersection of all your line segments with a horizontal line (not _the_ horizon, they'll vanish in a single point there, if they're parallel in the real world)

Comment: I'm sure you can take those 2D coordinates and calculate midpoints. it's just addition and then divide by 2. what questions do you have about that specifically? you didn't formulate questions, only _that_ you have questions.

Comment: What do you mean by distance between 2 lines? Distance between the upper ends? The lower ends? The midpoint of each line/ And by midpoint between 2 lines, I assume you mean midpoint of the 2 midpoints?

Comment: Can I measure the distance between 2 lines?

Comment: yes. now please address the given advice. what do you need to understand the task and the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are showing a 2d image that represents the projection of a 3d scene though a camera.

If you want to infer information about the 3d scene (lane width, for example) you need to know how the 3d scene was projected to create the 2d image. In order to do that you need to know the camera parameters (how it transforms the scene), as well as its position and orientation. Also, a single image is not (normally) enough to obtain a complete 3D reconstruction.

OpenCV gives the necessary tools for this. You can start by studying the [Camera Calibration and 3D Reconstruction](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/db7/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_calib3d.html) section.

Comment: I'm not working with the camera right now, I'm just trying to measure the distance between two lines on the photo.